# GAM: statistically comparing fit when changing covariates in gratia (R)

Tags: r, generalized-additive-model

I am using `gratia` to fit a gam model such as:

```
formula = as.formula(paste(Region, "~ 
      s(date, k=20) + ID"))
```

I would like to know if `date_centred_on_event1`:

```
formula = as.formula(paste(Region, "~ 
     s(date_centred_on_event1, k=20) + ID"))
```

provide a better fit than `date`.

What would be the best to statistically compared to two fits?

```
mod <- gam(formula, data = dat, 
           method = "REML")
appraise(mod)
summary(mod)
```

result for `date`:

```
Approximate significance of smooth terms:
         edf Ref.df     F  p-value    
s(age) 1.001  1.001 22.34 1.24e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.886   Deviance explained = 89.8%
-REML = 430.49  Scale est. = 16030     n = 76
```

result for `date_centred_on_event1`:

```
Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                  edf Ref.df     F p-value    
s(date_centred_on_event1) 3.803  4.806 12.55  <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =   0.92   Deviance explained = 93.1%
-REML = 421.26  Scale est. = 11255     n = 76
```

Since `R-sq.(adj)` and `Deviance explained` is superior to `date_centred_on_event1`, are those parameters the ones that I should use for comparisons?

Supposed that I repeat that for different `Region`. Would it be appropriate to perform something like a t-test or Wilcoxon across all the results obtained for each regions (`R-sq.(adj)` and `Deviance explained`) between `date_centred_on_event1` and `date`?
to be clear for example:

The test would compare:
`R-sq.(adj)` of `Region` A, `Region` B, `Region` C etc... fitted with `date_centred_on_event1`
to
`R-sq.(adj)` of `Region` A, `Region` B, `Region` C etc... fitted with `date`

---

thank you again for your comment.

I apologize, I think that I was not clear. My question here is does
`date_centred_on_event1` provides a better fit than `date`.

With

```
gam(Y ~ ID + Region + s(Date, by = Region), data = my_data, family = XXX, method = "REML")
```

I think we are comparing the difference between regions which is interesting but not what I wanted to do.

I also, realized that you were right, `ID` is a random effect.

In order to rectify that I modified my formula according to this link:
[https://fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2021/02/02/random-effects-in-gams/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwR3b.png)

it should be something like:

```
formula = Region1 ~ s(ID, date, bs = "re") + s(date, k = 20) + s(ID, bs = "re")
```

Then I would like to explore the fit which gives

```
#GAM
mod <- gam(formula, data = dat, method = "REML")
summary(mod)
draw(mod)
```

`date` is equal to `age`

```
Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)    42206       2350   17.96   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
            edf Ref.df         F  p-value    
s(ID,age) 6.487  7.000 1.569e+05  < 2e-16 ***
s(age)    2.995  3.793 4.618e+00  0.00306 ** 
s(ID)     6.627  7.000 8.609e+04 1.81e-06 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.961   Deviance explained = 96.9%
-REML = 617.25  Scale est. = 3.6452e+05  n = 76
```

[image]

Questions:

1. is my formula correct?
2. When I calculate the derivative

   df <- derivatives(mod, type = "central",  n = 100)

I have got:

```
Error in Summary.factor(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L,  : 
  ‘min’ not meaningful for factors
```

How can I fix that?

3. is it possible to have the partial effect of `date` in the unit that I was originally using? (here is it centered on zero)
4. What is the difference between the plot of the first ID and the second?
5. To go back to my original question:

I have in my dataset multiple Regions (1, 2, 3, 4..)
AND
another regressor (X-axis that is called `date_centred_on_event1`)

When using the same script with `date_centred_on_event1` I have got the following result:

`Growth_plate` is equal to `date_centred_on_event1`

```
Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)    42243       1174   35.98   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                     edf Ref.df       F  p-value    
s(ID,Growth_plate) 6.352  7.000  552.76  < 2e-16 ***
s(Growth_plate)    4.988  6.395    4.86 0.000333 ***
s(ID)              6.934  7.000 1594.36  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.968   Deviance explained = 97.6%
-REML = 608.97  Scale est. = 2.9088e+05  n = 76
```

[image]

We can see that the variance explain and R-sq is higher than with `date`
(Note that I have the same problem when calculating the derivative)

I would like to prove that `date_centred_on_event1` is a better regressor than `date` whatever the `Region` used in the Y-axis.

So my original idea was to calculate the variance explain and R-sq for each `Region` in the two groups `date_centred_on_event1` and `date` and then compare it with whatever test could be appropriate but it might not be the best way to do it right?

So maybe I way want to do something like:

```
m1_gam <- gam(Volume ~ Regressor:Region:time + s(ID, bs = 're') + s(ID, Regressor, bs = 're') + s(ID, Region, bs = 're') + s(Region, bs = 're') + s(Regressor, bs = 're'), data = dat2, method = 'REML')
```

the formula is not correct, I might need help to write it well.

`Volume` raw would contain all the values for regions 1, 2, 3, 4, etc...

`Regressor` would be if volume is either `date_centred_on_event1` or `date`

`ID` is the name of each subject

`time` the raw time values for either `date_centred_on_event1` or `date`

Column 1 : Region
Column 2 : Volume
Column 3 : Regressor
Column 4 : time
Column 5 : ID

```
1   Region1 15544.00    date_centred_on_event1  3.400000    1
2   Region1 15425.25    date_centred_on_event1  3.600000    1
3   Region1 15133.62    date_centred_on_event1  3.900000    1
4   Region1 15566.00    date_centred_on_event1  4.200000    1
5   Region1 15966.38    date_centred_on_event1  4.500000    1
6   Region1 15843.88    date    4.800000    2
7   Region1 15723.75    date    5.000000    2
8   Region2 15563.75    date    5.300000    2
9   Region2 15613.62    date    5.600000    2
10  Region2 15776.25    date    5.900000    2
11  Region2 14357.38    date    3.200000    3
12  Region2 15923.50    date    3.500000    3
13  Region2 15626.00    date    3.700000    3
14  Region3 15646.12    date    4.000000    3
```

and then compare the smooth difference_smooths()?

Thank you! sry for the long post!

Answer (score 2):

That would be a pretty bad way to do this.

What you want to do is fit something like

$$
\mathop{\mathbb{E}}(Y_i) = \text{ID} + \text{Region} + f_{\text{Region}(i)}(\text{Date}_i)
$$

where

1. $Y_i$ is the thing you measured,
2. $\mathop{\mathbb{E}}(Y_i)$ is the expectation of the thing you measured
3. $\text{Region}$ is a categorical factor with levels equal to the regions you measured $Y_i$ at,
4. $\text{ID}$ is whatever `ID` is in your formula - sounds like a subject or similar variable and if so, it is likely that should model that as a random effect not a fixed one,
5. $f_{\text{Region}(i)}(\text{Date}_i)$ is a smooth function of `Date` for each `Region`, with the subscript $\text{Region}(i)$ indexing the regions for the $i$th observation

in {mgcv}, this would be

```r
gam(Y ~ ID + Region + s(Date, by = Region), data = my_data,
    family = XXX, method = "REML")
```

replacing `XXX` with a suitable conditional distribution for the response.

Then you would compare the smooths using `difference_smooths()` in {gratia} for example.

This is but one way to compare the things you want to compare without fitting separate models.

Comment: Hello, thank you again for your comment. I apologize, I think that I was not clear.